# Select network interfaces from Camel Mina

Tags: apache-camel, apache-mina

Is there any way to configure the camel Mina component to select network interfaces? Currently my machine has 4 Ethernet cards installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Apache Mina 1.x has no such configuration. We looked into this years ago. Maybe Mina 2.x has a way of doing this? As we plan to provide a camel-mina2 component.